# Why my Js is not working in my react page?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, sidenav

I'm trying to implement this https://codepen.io/azouaoui-med/pen/wpBadb as one of my pages inside my react proj. But dropdown doesn't work and couldn't able to close side bar which functions by js. AM not getting any error. But it simply being a static page. How to make it to work? Anybody out there help me to resolve this is issue. Thanks in advance

PS: Am getting the same output as from codepen, not the one which shows down when clicking "Run code snippet"

[My output is something like this from my proj and also from code sandbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdaTE.jpg)

My codesandbox for reference : https://5vbl2.csb.app/

[Side bar which i tried using with dropdown](https://codepen.io/azouaoui-med/pen/wpBadb)

```js
$(".sidebar-dropdown > a").click(function() {
  $(".sidebar-submenu").slideUp(200);
  if (
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .hasClass("active")
  ) {
    $(".sidebar-dropdown").removeClass("active");
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .removeClass("active");
  } else {
    $(".sidebar-dropdown").removeClass("active");
    $(this)
      .next(".sidebar-submenu")
      .slideDown(200);
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .addClass("active");
  }
});

$("#close-sidebar").click(function() {
  $(".page-wrapper").removeClass("toggled");
});
$("#show-sidebar").click(function() {
  $(".page-wrapper").addClass("toggled");
});
```

```css
@keyframes swing {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotate(5deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes sonar {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
body {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}
.page-wrapper .sidebar-wrapper,
.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-brand > a,
.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-dropdown > a:after,
.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown .sidebar-submenu li a:before,
.sidebar-wrapper ul li a i,
.page-wrapper .page-content,
.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search input.search-menu,
.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search .input-group-text,
.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu ul li a,
#show-sidebar,
#close-sidebar {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

/*----------------page-wrapper----------------*/

.page-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
}

.page-wrapper .theme {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 2px;
}

.page-wrapper .theme.chiller-theme {
  background: #1e2229;
}

/*----------------toggeled sidebar----------------*/

.page-wrapper.toggled .sidebar-wrapper {
  left: 0px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .page-wrapper.toggled .page-content {
    padding-left: 300px;
  }
}
/*----------------show sidebar button----------------*/
#show-sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 10px;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0px;
  width: 35px;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.page-wrapper.toggled #show-sidebar {
  left: -40px;
}
/*----------------sidebar-wrapper----------------*/

.sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 260px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -300px;
  z-index: 999;
}

.sidebar-wrapper ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.sidebar-wrapper a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/*----------------sidebar-content----------------*/

.sidebar-content {
  max-height: calc(100% - 30px);
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar-content.desktop {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

/*--------------------sidebar-brand----------------------*/

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-brand {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-brand > a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-brand #close-sidebar {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
}
/*--------------------sidebar-header----------------------*/

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-header {
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-header .user-pic {
  float: left;
  width: 60px;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-header .user-pic img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-header .user-info {
  float: left;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-header .user-info > span {
  display: block;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-header .user-info .user-role {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-header .user-info .user-status {
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-header .user-info .user-status i {
  font-size: 8px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  color: #5cb85c;
}

/*-----------------------sidebar-search------------------------*/

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search > div {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

/*----------------------sidebar-menu-------------------------*/

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .header-menu span {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 15px 20px 5px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 8px 30px 8px 20px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu ul li a i {
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu ul li a:hover > i::before {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: swing ease-in-out 0.5s 1 alternate;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown > a:after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f105";
  font-style: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  background: 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 14px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown .sidebar-submenu ul {
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown .sidebar-submenu li {
  padding-left: 25px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown .sidebar-submenu li a:before {
  content: "\f111";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 8px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu ul li a span.label,
.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu ul li a span.badge {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown .sidebar-submenu li a .badge,
.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown .sidebar-submenu li a .label {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-submenu {
  display: none;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown.active > a:after {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  right: 17px;
}

/*--------------------------side-footer------------------------------*/

.sidebar-footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar-footer > a {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar-footer > a .notification {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.badge-sonar {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #980303;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.badge-sonar:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 2px solid #980303;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: sonar 1.5s infinite;
}

/*--------------------------page-content-----------------------------*/

.page-wrapper .page-content {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.page-wrapper .page-content > div {
  padding: 20px 40px;
}

.page-wrapper .page-content {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

/*------scroll bar---------------------*/

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
  height: 7px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #525965;
  border: 0px none #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #525965;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
  background: #525965;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0px none #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover {
  background: transparent;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track:active {
  background: transparent;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  background: transparent;
}


/*-----------------------------chiller-theme-------------------------------------------------*/

.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper {
    background: #31353D;
}

.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-header,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu {
    border-top: 1px solid #3a3f48;
}

.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search input.search-menu,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search .input-group-text {
    border-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-header .user-info .user-role,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-header .user-info .user-status,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search input.search-menu,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search .input-group-text,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-brand>a,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu ul li a,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-footer>a {
    color: #818896;
}

.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu ul li:hover>a,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown.active>a,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-header .user-info,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-brand>a:hover,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-footer>a:hover i {
    color: #b8bfce;
}

.page-wrapper.chiller-theme.toggled #close-sidebar {
    color: #bdbdbd;
}

.page-wrapper.chiller-theme.toggled #close-sidebar:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper ul li:hover a i,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-dropdown .sidebar-submenu li a:hover:before,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search input.search-menu:focus+span,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown.active a i {
    color: #16c7ff;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 10px rgba(22, 199, 255, 0.5);
}

.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu ul li a i,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown div,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search input.search-menu,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search .input-group-text {
    background: #3a3f48;
}

.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .header-menu span {
    color: #6c7b88;
}

.chiller-theme .sidebar-footer {
    background: #3a3f48;
    box-shadow: 0px -1px 5px #282c33;
    border-top: 1px solid #464a52;
}

.chiller-theme .sidebar-footer>a:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}

.chiller-theme .sidebar-footer>a:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrapper chiller-theme toggled">
  <a id="show-sidebar" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark" href="#">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
  <nav id="sidebar" class="sidebar-wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar-content">
      <div class="sidebar-brand">
        <a href="#">pro sidebar</a>
        <div id="close-sidebar">
          <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-header">
        <div class="user-pic">
          <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/azouaoui-med/pro-sidebar-template/gh-pages/src/img/user.jpg" alt="User picture">
        </div>
        <div class="user-info">
          <span class="user-name">Jhon
            <strong>Smith</strong>
          </span>
          <span class="user-role">Administrator</span>
          <span class="user-status">
            <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
            <span>Online</span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- sidebar-header  -->
      <div class="sidebar-search">
        <div>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control search-menu" placeholder="Search...">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <span class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- sidebar-search  -->
      <div class="sidebar-menu">
        <ul>
          <li class="header-menu">
            <span>General</span>
          </li>
          <li class="sidebar-dropdown">
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
              <span>Dashboard</span>
              <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning">New</span>
            </a>
            <div class="sidebar-submenu">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Dashboard 1
                    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">Pro</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Dashboard 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Dashboard 3</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="sidebar-dropdown">
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              <span>E-commerce</span>
              <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">3</span>
            </a>
            <div class="sidebar-submenu">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Products

                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Orders</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Credit cart</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="sidebar-dropdown">
            <a href="#">
              <i class="far fa-gem"></i>
              <span>Components</span>
            </a>
            <div class="sidebar-submenu">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">General</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Panels</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Tables</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Icons</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Forms</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="sidebar-dropdown">
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-chart-line"></i>
              <span>Charts</span>
            </a>
            <div class="sidebar-submenu">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Pie chart</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Line chart</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Bar chart</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Histogram</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="sidebar-dropdown">
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
              <span>Maps</span>
            </a>
            <div class="sidebar-submenu">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Google maps</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Open street map</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="header-menu">
            <span>Extra</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
              <span>Documentation</span>
              <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Beta</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
              <span>Calendar</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-folder"></i>
              <span>Examples</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- sidebar-menu  -->
    </div>
    <!-- sidebar-content  -->
    <div class="sidebar-footer">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning notification">3</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-success notification">7</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
        <span class="badge-sonar"></span>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- sidebar-wrapper  -->
  <main class="page-content">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Pro Sidebar</h2>
      <hr>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
          <p>This is a responsive sidebar template with dropdown menu based on bootstrap 4 framework.</p>
          <p> You can find the complete code on <a href="https://github.com/azouaoui-med/pro-sidebar-template" target="_blank">
              Github</a>, it contains more themes and background image option</p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
          <iframe src="https://ghbtns.com/github-btn.html?user=azouaoui-med&repo=pro-sidebar-template&type=star&count=true&size=small" frameborder="0" scrolling="0" width="90px" height="30px"></iframe>
          <iframe src="https://ghbtns.com/github-btn.html?user=azouaoui-med&repo=pro-sidebar-template&type=fork&count=true&size=small" frameborder="0" scrolling="0" width="90px" height="30px"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
          <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            <h4 class="alert-heading">New !</h4>
            <p>New react pro sidebar library is now available on <a href="https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pro-sidebar" target="_blank">npm</a> <a href="https://github.com/azouaoui-med/react-pro-sidebar" target="_blank">
                <img alt="GitHub stars" src="https://img.shields.io/github/stars/azouaoui-med/react-pro-sidebar?style=social" />
              </a></p>
            <a href="https://github.com/azouaoui-med/react-pro-sidebar" target="_blank" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-2">
              Github</a>
            <a href="https://azouaoui-med.github.io/react-pro-sidebar" target="_blank" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
              Demo</a>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <h5>More templates</h5>
      <hr>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <div class="card rounded-0 p-0 shadow-sm">
            <img src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/25878302/58369568-a49b2480-7efc-11e9-9ca9-2be44afacda1.png" class="card-img-top rounded-0" alt="Angular pro sidebar">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
              <h6 class="card-title">Angular Pro Sidebar</h6>
              <a href="https://github.com/azouaoui-med/angular-pro-sidebar" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Github</a>
              <a href="https://azouaoui-med.github.io/angular-pro-sidebar/demo/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Demo</a>
              <hr>
              <a href="https://github.com/azouaoui-med/react-pro-sidebar" target="_blank">
                <img alt="GitHub stars" src="https://img.shields.io/github/stars/azouaoui-med/angular-pro-sidebar?style=social" />
              </a>
              <a href="https://github.com/azouaoui-med/react-pro-sidebar" target="_blank">
                <img alt="GitHub stars" src="https://img.shields.io/github/forks/azouaoui-med/angular-pro-sidebar?style=social" />
              </a>

            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <div class="card rounded-0 p-0 shadow-sm">
            <img src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/25878302/58369258-33f20900-7ef8-11e9-8ff3-b277cb7ed7b4.PNG" class="card-img-top rounded-0" alt="Angular pro sidebar">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
              <h6 class="card-title">Angular Dashboard</h6>
              <a href="https://github.com/azouaoui-med/lightning-admin-angular" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Github</a>
              <a href="https://azouaoui-med.github.io/lightning-admin-angular/demo/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Demo</a>
              <hr>
              <a href="https://github.com/azouaoui-med/react-pro-sidebar" target="_blank">
                <img alt="GitHub stars" src="https://img.shields.io/github/stars/azouaoui-med/lightning-admin-angular?style=social" />
              </a>
              <a href="https://github.com/azouaoui-med/react-pro-sidebar" target="_blank">
                <img alt="GitHub stars" src="https://img.shields.io/github/forks/azouaoui-med/lightning-admin-angular?style=social" />
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>

      <footer class="text-center">
        <div class="mb-2">
          <small>
            © 2020 made with <i class="fa fa-heart" style="color:red"></i> by - <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://azouaoui.netlify.com">
              Mohamed Azouaoui
            </a>
          </small>
        </div>

        <div>
          <a href="https://github.com/azouaoui-med" target="_blank">
            <img alt="GitHub followers" src="https://img.shields.io/github/followers/azouaoui-med?label=github&style=social" />
          </a>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/azouaoui_med" target="_blank">
            <img alt="Twitter Follow" src="https://img.shields.io/twitter/follow/azouaoui_med?label=twitter&style=social" />
          </a>
        </div>
      </footer>

    </div>

  </main>
  <!-- page-content" -->
</div>
<!-- page-wrapper -->
```

This is the javascript which am uisng

Comment: I get errors in the browser console when I open your codesandbox link. Also, the javascript you've provided in your question appears to use jQuery, do you load that? I'm not sure if jQuery code plays well with React. Also, mentioned on the codepen.io link, the author of that sidebar has authored one for React at: https://github.com/azouaoui-med/react-pro-sidebar

Comment: Thanks for the response @BenStephens, but https://github.com/azouaoui-med/react-pro-sidebar i've tried this also but i don't have a proper code for that. So i thought of using simple html & css, but jquery isn't working. YEs i've loaded jquery in my page. Codesandbox is working fine now. Please have a look.

Comment: Did you save your changes? https://codesandbox.io/s/5vbl2 still shows errors in the console. And I don't see the javascript code that you've got in your question anywhere.

Comment: @BenStephens have attached my output from both my proj and code sandbox

Answer (score 0):

[This is how it looks like for me, i can deal with icons but for functionality am helpless.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpCYj.jpg)

Comment: I hope console errors don't create any problem here since I've my another code which is working fine has some console errors.(PS : I DON'T HAVE THIS CONSOLE ERROR IN MY WORKING PROJECT) questions Which I've asked for, let me change it to "Why does jQuery doesn't work inside my reactjs". Help me to create the same working sidenav in codepen. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Adding this here rather than a comment, so that I can show the picture ...

When I go to:

https://codesandbox.io/s/5vbl2?file=/src/App.js:200-335

This is what I see:

[image: codesandbox image]

The highlighted code just after the start of the Secdoc function is the only bit of jQuery code I can find (and doesn't match what you had in your question); the panel at the bottom left shows the console erros that I keep mentioning.